# Creating a new column equals the logarithm of another column in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns, logarithm

As titled.I tried to create a new column called level_log by taking the logarithm of an existing column named "level"
I tried:

```
chol$level_log <-chol$log(level)
```

But it shows:

```
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `log`.
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

What's the problem here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: chol$level_log <- log(chol$level)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to wrap your entire `chol$level` in a log rather than only the column, i.e. change

`chol$level_log <-chol$log(level)`

to

`chol$level_log <-log(chol$level)`

This is happening because R doesn't know what level is on its own. What if you had multiple data loaded and several of them had a column called level? In order to avoid this confusion it requires that you specify the exact column you mean, including where that column comes from.